# Why are parentheses used around a class name in Java?

Tags: java

I came across some code and cannot understand a certain aspect of it although i have done some extensive searching!

My question is: why are classes sometimes declared within parentheses like in the following code?

```
public class Animal {

    public static void hide() {
        System.out.println("The hide method in Animal.");
    }

    public void override() {
        System.out.println("The override method in Animal.");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    public static void hide() {
        System.out.println("The hide method in Cat.");
    }

    public void override() {
        System.out.println("The override method in Cat.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Animal myAnimal = (Animal)myCat;
        myAnimal.hide();
        myAnimal.override();
    }
}
```

where my focus is on this line of code in particular:

```
            Animal myAnimal = (Animal)myCat;
```

I believe it has something to do with the fact that one class extends another but am unsure what the class defined within parentheses signifies.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a typecast but in this case the typecast is not necessary - since `Cat` is a sub-type of Animal. Typecasts are necessary when you want to assign a Super-Type to a Sub-Type, e.g. `Cat cat = (Cat)someAnimal;`. If you do this you'll have to make sure that in the Variable either a `Cat` or a sub-type of `Cat` is contained, e.g. using `instanceof`. Otherwise Java will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: in this particular case, since Cat extends Animal and myAnimal is already Animal, you do not need to cast myCat to Animal. So, Animal myAnimal = myCat; would've worked.

Comment: brackets `[]` -- braces `{}` -- parentheses `()` -- "angle brackets" `<>`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the terminology used for various types of "brackets".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're seeing is a cast to tell the compiler it's ok to assign a Cat to an Animal.

Casts are for cases where the compiler can't safely convert one type to another, either because it doesn't know what the types involved are, or because the conversion would lose information (for instance, if you have a double that you want to store in a variable of type float).

In your example the cast is totally unnecessary because Cat extends Animal; since all Cats are Animals, the compiler doesn't need an explicit cast to tell it it can assign a Cat to an Animal.

Casting should be reserved for special occasions. If you use explicit casts regularly then it may mean you're not getting the most benefit out of the type system.

Answer (score 7):

This is a cast - the `myCat` variable which is of type `Cat` is being cast to the base class `Animal`.

This means it can be considered to be an `Animal`.

This is a basic function of [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in Java.

---

As [@Sebastian Koppehel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542377/sebastian-koppehel) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728356/why-are-brackets-used-around-a-class-name-in-java/11728387#comment15562534_11728387), the cast in this case is not needed - the `myAnimal` variable (of type `Animal`) can accept any type that implements `Animal`.

Comment: And this basic feature of inheritance means that the cast is *unnecessary* in this instance. You need casts when you know an object is of a certain class but the compiler can't know that for some reason. In this case the compiler knows it and the cast is only syntactic sugar.

Comment: So the fact that `Cat` extends `Animal` makes the casting pointless? I.e. does the same job?

Comment: @Sadiq_S86 - Essentially, yes. The cast is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the code produces correct output, if you have to cast the object to a parent class and then call the static method of the parent class, the classes may need to be designed in better fashion. Inheritance in Java is supposed to provide access to common methods and fields.  If one needs to code a static method in a Parent class and call it using object of child classes, then the relationship between parent and child class is not clear cut.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly guaranteeing compiler/runtime that the cat reference type you are passing is type of Animal. In java, it is called as **casting**.

While runtime if this contract is not honored (That means there is no relationship defined between cat and Animal) you will get `ClassCastException`.